# Is there a location to find the personnel roster of the No. 300 Polish Bomber Squadron during WW2?

Tags: world-war-two, military, britain, historical-research, research-techniques

I'm working on a research project and I am looking to confirm that certain individuals were part of the **No. 300 Polish Bomber Squadron** during WW2.

**Is there a place online or offline where one could find a list of the bomber crew personnel that went through this particular squadron?** It would be best if the source also had their dates of service, missions flown, kill-count, injuries sustained, date released from active service or transfer, etc.

*At the absolute minimum, I would need the list of names of the various members of the squadron through the war years.*

I have seen [the website](http://www.polishsquadronsremembered.com/300/300Squadron.html) devoted to this particular squadron but as far as I can tell it does not have an exhaustive list the personnel attached to it.

Comment: The Air Ministry or equivalent Archives...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether a list has been compiled and published, but it should be possible to extract the information (at least for air crew) from the [Operational Records of 300 Squadron](http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/details/r/C1912770).

These have been digitised, and can be accessed from the website of the [UK National Archives](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/).  However, note that **these records are not free to download**.

An alternative may be to visit the UK National Archives at Kew in person (or hire a professional researcher to do so on your behalf) where the records can be viewed (and photographed) free-of-charge.